# Deploy a self-contained .NET Core application with Azure DevOps App Service Deploy task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment

From a local machine I can publish a .NET Core application to Azure Web Service as a self-hosted application by defining `<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>` in publish profile.

**App Service Deploy** task in Azure DevOps pipeline publishes it to IIS by default.
How configure it to publish as self-hosted?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got this working in Azure Dev Ops with my Blazor Server Side App that is targeting a preview version of .NET Core 3.0. To do this without creating a yaml file for your build definition you should be able to add the following argument on your dotnet publish task if you're not targeting a preview version of .NET Core.

```
-r win-x86 --self-contained true
```

The -r is the run time that you want to target, in my case I selected win-x86 since that is what my app service is configured to use. Then just add the self contained argument. Your full argument will probably look something like this:

```
--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) -r win-x86 --self-contained true --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

This link covers the dotnet publish command. This is the same command that is executed when you publish from your local machine [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli)

The full list of run time identifiers can be found here:
[run time identfiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#using-rids)

gist of the complete build definition in yaml file
[yaml](https://gist.github.com/mrutherford2/b38042a9c8b958de9524663b2ffc21e6)

Comment: As a side note, it seems that specifying `--self-contained true` is redundant if you are already specifying a runtime using the `-r|--runtime` parameter. Per the chart in the docs, for SDK 2.1 and 3.x the commands are: `dotnet publish` for a runtime-dependent cross-platform binary or `dotnet publish -r <RID>` for a self-contained executable. 

 Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/